# How to extract value from specific P-tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to only extract the value for Acid(`5.9 g/L`) and Alcohol(`14.5%`)?

I thought of using `find_all('p')`, but it is giving me all the p tag while I only need two of them.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly the two data points you are trying to extract have in common? Are you looking to get all the numbers (because then you're leaving out the ph and sugar)? Or maybe you want the numbers underneath "Acid" and "Alcohol%"?  Depending on what you want, the approach will vary.

Comment: Yes, I just want the numbers underneath "Acid" and “Alcohol%”, any idea how to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `<h3>` by its content and from there its direct sibling:

```
soup.select_one('h3:-soup-contains("Acid") + p').text
```

You could adapt this also for other elements if they are known otherwise you have to select all and check content against `list`

```
l = ['Acid','...']
for e in soup.select('.wine-specs p'):
    if e.text in l:
        print(e.text)
```